# How to provide property file name dynamically in java

Tags: java

Hi I am using two property files. one is for application configuration and another one is for object repository. I am going to use these two properties through out my application. for each and every testcase I am initialising property and access the files using property object. But I want to initialise property in a separate method in separate class.Also I want to call the method in another class and access the property files using that initialised property object. I don't know how to do this. Please give me a hand for this task to be done.Thanks in advance

**Below is my code**

```
public class PropertiesExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = null;
        String baseUrl;
        File file = new File("/home/vaav/workspace/PropertiesExample/config.properties");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fileIO = null;

        try{
            fileIO = new FileInputStream(file);
            prop.load(fileIO);
            fileIO.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/vaav/workspace/PropertiesExample/lib/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        baseUrl = prop.getProperty("URL");
        driver.get(baseUrl+"/");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("Login.btnAdmin"))).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty("Login.txtUsername"))).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("userName"));
        driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty("Login.txtPassword"))).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("password"));
        driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty("Login.btnSignIn"))).click();
    }

}
```

I want to do the property related stuff in another file and make reusability of that code

Comment: This question has been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677123/dynamic-property-handler

Answer (score 0):

Pick a default filename and location for your property file. E.g. "./config.properties" which would assume the properties file is in the user.dir on startup. Or load the same file from the classpath via the Resource Loader e.g.

```
    final InputStream stream =
       this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
properties.load(stream);
```

But also give the option to override the default location via a System Property. System.

```
 String configLocation = System.getProperties().getProperty("properties.location");
```

If configLocation is not null, use the user specified location. Otherwise use the default.

Answer (score 0):

You could allow the user to specify it by a command line argument:

```
String configLocation == "default/location/config.properties"
if(args.length >= 1){
    configLocation = args[0];
    //You could also test here that the file exists
}
```